# Python Could not find the Qt platform plugin

Tags: python, qt, plugins

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

I installed everything about qt but it didn't fix

Comment: you need to let the application have access to "platforms/qwindows.dll" library. Typically this "platforms" subdir is in the same parent directory as your executable.

Comment: can you help me how to do it